# How to get code prompt by PHPDoc in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using an uncommon php framework in PhpStorm.

Unfortunately, I found that functions of Model classes in this framework don't have prompt in PhpStorm. Somebody told me I can resolve this problem by using PHPDoc.

Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: Did you add the framework as an external library?

Comment: No,the framework is under my project.

Comment: Then perhaps you can explain better what your problem is. We don't even know what framework you're using. And "functions of Model classes in this framework don't have prompt in PHPStorm" is not very clear.

Comment: I'm using thinkphp, which is wrote by Chinese and major used in China. I meant that thinkphp has an D() function ,which is used to instantiate customized model classes.But after I used D() to instantiate some model class,the IDE can't intellisense functions under the class.The framework also has a M() function,which is used to instantiate framework's model class,then do common database operates,such as find()/delete()/insert()...,but after I used M(),the IDE can't intellisense functions under model class of the framework ,either.

Comment: Try adding `/** @var NameOfYourModelClass */` directly above the line where you instantiate the class. Obviously, replace `NameOfYourModelClass` with the name of whatever class you are instantiating. That should work, but it's very hard to help you beyond that without some sample code and more details about which class(es) you are instantiating.

Comment: Lets assume you have `$abc = MyFunctionThatCreatesSomeClass();`. You can add `/** @var MyClass $abc */` on the line before and it will tell IDE that from this point the `$abc` variable is an instance of `MyClass`. Some specs on PHPDoc can be found here: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md